# TensorFlow register.h file not found in iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, tensorflow, xcode10

I am building the TensorFlow iOS project and having just this one issue.

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
```

Xcode error states the file cannot be found. I am able to find the actual file, but am not sure how to "assign" it to the project? I followed the steps online, and everything else went okay.

Is this a common / known bug?

Answer (score 0):

In Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries include the libtensorflow-lite.a file from tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/lib/libtensorflow-lite.a (you probably need to go to "Add Other..." to do it). Include tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/lib as a Library search path. Then, make sure your header search paths contain:

- the root folder of tensorflow,
- tensorflow/lite/downloads
- tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers
- tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers/include/flatbuffers